# How to contribute capital from 401k or IRA to a Series LLC?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, limited-liability-company

I am new to this thread and I'm seeking some basic advice or comment for this matter.

**Please assume that any investment risks are taken into consideration.**

### Objective:

I would like to bootstrap an investment LLC that will be dedicated to invest in local real-estate, small businesses and the stock market. The purpose of creating a Series LLC is that I would like to have each branch completely separated in order to isolate any kind of debt in case of bankruptcy and also to get involved in multiple industries. However, I'm aware of the fact that a single-member LLC might not be completely protected in these matters as I file the tax and earnings in my income statement.

### Questions

1. What are the ***pros and cons*** of transferring funds from the 401k or
   the IRA to the LLC for investment purposes, (directed by me) (is
   it worth it for small amount of funds)?
2. Is there a tax benefit under a single-member llc?
3. Can the Master LLC start operating as an investment firm (make profits) and then use the funds to acquire small businesses, invest in real estate or start a branch LLC in a different market?

Comment: A transfer from a 401(k) or IRA would be considered a disbursement and subject to applicable taxes and penalties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transfer from a 401(k) or IRA to a non-retirement account would be considered a disbursement and subject to applicable taxes and penalties.

It sounds like you are wanting to use your retirement funds to do non-traditional investing (real-estate, etc.) That is *possible* with a *self-directed IRA*, but it has significant limitations. The basic principle is that you (or immediate family members) cannot directly benefit from the IRA, either monetarily or otherwise. For example, you couldn't use the IRA to buy a rental property and let your family stay in it rent-free.  Additionally, any profits generated by the IRA need to stay within the IRA, and you can't use it to reimburse you for related expenses. Any profits or expenses that are distributed to you (or your family) would be treated as disbursements and subject to taxes and penalties as applicable. The goal is to prevent you from funneling money out of the IRA without paying tax (or penalty) on it.

To my knowledge, creating an LLC would not shield you from those limitations. You could not receive any funds or benefits from the LLC. It might help protect you from *liability*, but not *tax*.

That said, I would encourage you to find a local CPA or advisor that does self-directed IRAs to help you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is the penalty only tax related? Also, if I max out the contributions to both accounts can’t I use the excess as a contributed capital for the LLC?

Comment: The penalty would be for a disbursement of retirement funds before reaching retirement age.  Any penalties relating to underpayment of taxes (which is also possible) would be separate.

Comment: "if I max out the contributions to both accounts can’t I use the excess as a contributed capital for the LLC" Sure, but there would be no tax benefit to my knowledge.